# postion:absolute and left:0 not putting ul at left

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

**this is my html i just want my dropdown to move to the left of the screen.i have used inline style to set position absolute and left:0  but its not working please help me so can i move on and learn more.**
*i have used bootstrap to make this navigation bar and tried using absolute positioning but it is not working??do not know why??*

```
<!Doctype html>
    <html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>
    Tours and Travels
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">


    </head>

       //navigation bar
    <body>
    <header class ="navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" >
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <nav role="navigation">
       <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->


        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav"  >
            <li class="active"><a href="./index.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"  >
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Packages <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="positon:absolute; left:0;">
               //this is dropdown i want to move to the left of the screen

                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>




              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="padding:0.5%;" >
            <li><button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      Launch</button></li>

          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </nav>
    </div>
    </header>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: For starters, you've mis-spelt `positon`. It should be `position`.

Comment: maybe id=dropdown list element use style position:relative

Comment: Just update `<li class="dropdown" style="position:inherit" >`

Comment: i have corrected the spelling of position but still not working

Comment: thanx Super User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most browsers have some default `padding` on the `ul` element (e.g., in Chrome it's `40px`). You can set it to `0` to move the list items all the way left, or leave a little bit so you can still see the list markers.

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="position:absolute; left:0; padding: 0;">
    <!-- this is dropdown i want to move to the left of the screen -->
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
 </ul>
```